# Dupe but no dupe

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Marking/closing questions as a duplicate is a delicate subject, and there is a thin line between whether a post is a duplicate or not.

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616738/how-to-close-a-new-firefox-window-from-terminalcfct-command-is-not-working/616767#616767) however hurts my eyes. While OP clearly mentions he wants to close *the latest opened window (instance)* of Firefox, the question was closed as a duplicate of a question about *closing a tab* of Firefox. Quite different. I even explained it in the comment.

An interesting detail is that the first one to mark as a duplicate also answered the question *after marking it as duplicate*.

Moreover, the supposed duplicate does not offer a solution sideways as well.

Can this be undone?

Comment: Voted to re-open...  You can do that too!  :/

Comment: Couldn't make it in time to nominate it for reopening, it's reopened already!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes.

For the record, questions are only duplicates when the *questions* are the same. Answer overlap is a fact of life, let it happen. People are going to search for *their* problem, not someone else's similar problem.

Comment: Paying attention doesnt hurt either.